# email confirmation

Tags: cognito-forms

How can I have the email that is sent to me after a submission look just like the form when I am filling it out. What I mean is that my form is edited with different fonts and a logo but when I get the email submission none of that shows up

Answer (score 2):

Cognito Forms does not currently support the ability to customize the appearance of notification/confirmation emails. I would recommend submitting a [feature request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/featurerequest/) so that your idea may be implemented in the future.